# Why is my state null in my JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to execute the below application and I receive an error that "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null`". Why am I getting a null state? Why am I unable to read checked?

Receiving error in Checkbox.js in the `if` statement i.e.

```
if (this.state.checked) {
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';

ReactDOM.render(<Checkbox />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Checkbox.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Checkbox extends Component {
    getInitialState(){
        return {checked: false}
    }
    handleCheck(){
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    }
    render() {
        var message
        if (this.state.checked) {
            message = "Checked"
        } else {
            message = "Unchecked"
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <label><input type = "checkbox" onChange = {this.handleCheck}></input></label>
                <p>This box is {message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Checkbox;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using latest version of React with ES6. "getInitialState" is deprecated.

Instead.

```
class Checkbox extends Component{
    state = {
      checked: false,
    }
}
```

Also use PureComponent istead of Component as Component do deep object re-concilation checks.

Comment: thanks but now it throws an error as "Checkbox.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"  is this.setState also deprecated which i am using in handleCheck function

Comment: PureComponent vs Component is a different matter. In any case, Component does no object reconciliation (it renders on every setState), while PureComponent does a shallow check to avoid re-rendering when having the same props/state.

Comment: @DanielAndrei, it was just a suggestion at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting state correctly because your method is not bound.

You can do this instead :

```
    handleCheck = () => {
      this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    };
```

or in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {checked: false};
  this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor instead of getInitialState :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Checkbox extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.setState({checked: false});
    }
    handleCheck(){
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    }
    render() {
        var message
        if (this.state.checked) {
            message = "Checked"
        } else {
            message = "Unchecked"
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <label><input type = "checkbox" onChange = {this.handleCheck}></input></label>
                <p>This box is {message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Checkbox;
```